# Do browser vendors make crash statistics publicly available?

Tags: browser, crash-dumps, crash-reports

Mozilla has http://crash-stats.mozilla.com

Do other vendors have such a site? Is it possible to see crash stats for a particular url/domain?

Comment: I think that belongs to superuser or serverfault

Comment: I debated the options, but this one doesn't fit neatly. I'm approaching this as a developer who wants to investigate a crashing issue on a particular site. As such, I think it's best here.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla is the only where I know that such a public database exists. Internet Explorer definitely hasn´t anything like this and chrome doesn´t offer any informations about this. But I think, that the crash data only will be publicly available for opensource browsers